# Enigmail in Thunderbird works only with root

Tags: root, thunderbird, gnupg, enigmail

Hi I have a problem with in Thunderbird with enigmail and pinentry-qt4. I went through several tutorials and forums and followed all the steps. Now I found out that it works fine when I run Thunderbird with root privileges. 
Then I tried to give all necessairy permissions for pinentry and gpg to my normal user but it does not work.

Using Thunderbird as root is not a workaround, because when I exit and start it again it won't remember my profile anymore and I have to set up Thunderbird again.

So I think it is a problem whit  the access rights of Thunderbird. Can anyone help? Thanks alot.

Comment: What "does not work"? Helpful answers will only work out if you provide much more details. Are there any error messages? What is working fine, where do you get stuck?

Comment: @Jens  I get an error message:  gpg: Encryption failed - no private key found.  It's in German:   
`Fehler – Entschlüsselung fehlgeschlagen

gpg: Entschlüsselung fehlgeschlagen: Kein geheimer Schlüssel`

Comment: I have the following access rights:  
`drwxrwxrwx  4 alpolo alpolo   4096 Mai 14 11:47 .thunderbird    
drwxrwx---  4 alpolo alpolo   4096 Mär  6 21:22 .mozilla`

Comment: It looks like you created the private keys from your root account. Switch to the root account (`sudo su - `), run `gpg --export-secret-keys [key-id]`, and import it to your normal user's account.

Comment: They are already in my normal user account under `/home/alpolo/.gnupg`   `-rw-rw---- 1 alpolo alpolo   2240 Mai 12 23:20 pubring.gpg` and `-rw-rw---- 1 alpolo alpolo   4897 Mai 12 23:20 secring.gpg`

Comment: @Ben I can export the messages from Thunderbird and decrypt them via the commandline tool with the normal user account `gpg -d testemail.eml`

Comment: To make sure it is not a Thunderbird/Enigmail/configuration issue, try creating a new profile by moving `~/.thunderbird` to a temporary location.

Comment: I moved my profile to a temporary location and created a new profile. Enigmail is still not asking me for a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.

Apparently you need to give the right permissions to `~./.gnupg`:

```
sudo chmod 777 .gnupg/ -R
```